# How to use existing .so file in my other android project in windows PC?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I have to use ffmpeg library for video editing application in android. I have no experience in `JNI` or `NDK`. but I have `ffmpeg.so` file. Can I directly use it in my new android application?

I am using it but generating error: `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load videokit: findLibrary returned null`

If not, what are the steps to generate .so file? I have search lot of things but all are in mostly ubuntu. How to generate in windows or mac os? Can i decompile my existing .so file?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14824558/2310673) may help you.

Comment: if you have alredy the .so you have to put inside libs/armeabi and load it with System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");

Comment: I have already tried that, but it still not working. same error thrown.